# MYSQL знаки вопроса вместо кириллицы

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Искал с похожей проблемой, ничего не помогло. При добавлении записи через phpmyadmin, запись отображается корректно, когда отправляю форму через сайт, вместо русского текста вижу знаки вопроса. Кодировка utf8_general_ci
Куда копать? Как исправлять?

Возникает только на моем VPS (ubuntu 18) , тестил на винде через локальную сеть, все работает правильно

Comment: Попробуйте указать кодировку в spring.datasource.url
как описано в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677740/spring-data-jpa-utf-8-encoding-not-working

Comment: используйте UTF8mb4 вместо UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Помогла **"**?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8 **"** строчка в application.properties
Спасибо за помощь *Alexey Loskutov*